# ¿Como devolver true o false al ejecutar una funcion en php?

Tags: php

Hola tengo una pregunta como se devulve true o false segun se ejecute una funcion en php
por ejemplo eh creado esta pequeña funcion para comprobar si existen o no valores en una tabla mysql

```
  public function showUsers($idAccounts)
    {

        $search = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT usuarios from usuarios where cuentas_id = :id");
        $search->bindParam(':id', $idAccounts, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $search->execute();
        if ($search->rowCount() >= 1) {
           return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
       
    }
```

Pero al ejecutar la funcion no me devulve nada pero si por ejemplo uso un echo en las condiciones

```
  public function showUsers($idAccounts)
    {

        $search = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT usuarios from usuarios where cuentas_id = :id");
        $search->bindParam(':id', $idAccounts, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $search->execute();
        if ($search->rowCount() >= 1) {
           echo 'si existen registros';
        } else {
           echo 'no existen registros';
        }
       
    }
```

en efecto me valida la funcion y me dice si hay o no usuarios, pero no entiendo como puedo mostrar o devolver un true o false al ejecutar la funcion

Comment: Estás confundiendo *"devolver un valor"* con *"imprimir un valor en pantalla"*. Los valore se devuelven con `return LOQUESEA`, pero eso no significa que eso vaya a verse en pantalla! Eso solo *"saca"* el valor de la función, tal que así: `$valor = showUsers($loquesea);`. Luego lo que tú hagas con `$valor` es cosa tuya. Puedes usarlo para llamar a otra función, para ver qué tiene o directamente imprimirlo con un `echo`. PERO `ECHO` NO DEVUELVE UN VALOR, SOLO LO MUESTRA POR PANTALLA!! No puedes usar `echo` para escribir lógica de tu programa, para eso se usa `return`

Comment: ya entiendo creo que voy a tener que reformular esta pregunta gracias.

Comment: Aparte de lo que te señala @Benito-B me permito señalar otras cosas. En primer lugar, el Manual de PHP es claro con respecto  a `rowCount()`, y dice que no conviene usarlo para contar filas de una consulta `SELECT`, porque puede fallar en algunos contextos. El método 100% seguro para contar filas es un `SELECT COUNT(*)`, haciendo `fetch` de la columna que devuelve el total de registros. Por otra parte, puedes simplificar bastante el código devolviendo simplemente el resultado de la comparación, sin `if ... else`, lo cual aquí es redundante. Basta con un `return $search->rowCount() >= 1;` ...

Comment: ... PERO no olvides lo dicho antes, y evita usar `rowCount()` en este contexto. Dado que el título de la pregunta es: *Cómo devolver `true` o `false`*, pues la respuesta es, **haciendo simplemente `return` de la comparación sin más, pues la comparación en sí misma ya devuelve un booleano**. Luego, si al recibir el `return` quieres imprimir algo, puedes simplificar también usando un ternario, por ejemplo: `echo (showUsers($idAccounts)) ? 'si existen registros' : 'no existen registros';`

Comment: gracias por las respuestas

Answer (score 2):

No tienes que reformular nada, tal y como dijo Benito, confundes el return.
Return es para devolver el valor como tal, en este caso es un booleano, el cual puedes analizar de acuerdo a la funcion.

```
<?php
function trueFalse()
{
    $truefalse = 0;
    if ($truefalse == 0) {
       return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Acá te dejo unas cuantas formas de ver y validar que valor retorna dicha funcion

```
//retorna true, pero esto no se vee, dado que solo retorna el booleano
truefalse();

//retorna 1, dado que al imprimir un booleano, estos se analizan como 1 y 0 (true y false)
echo truefalse(); 

//Validacion que analiza la funcion, devolviendo el primer valor de ser true, o el segundo de ser false
//Retorna texto1
echo trueFalse() ? 'texto1' : 'texto2'; 

//Validacion basica que imprime un echo si es true
if(trueFalse() == true){ 
    echo "texto que dice que es true";
}

//Validacion basica que imprime un echo si es 1
if(trueFalse() == 1){ 
    echo "texto que dice que es true";
}

//retorna bool(true) dado que se analiza la estructura de lo que retorna, un bool con valor true.
var_dump(truefalse());
```